# Removing duplicates before copying to clipboard

Tags: java, textarea, duplicates, clipboard

I have a program which copies the contents of a text area to the clipboard. The program reads information from a file to the text area. I would like to remove duplicate information as i copy to the clipboard. Is this possible or would it be better to remove duplicates before writing to the text area?

Additional information: I have a button which copies the content to the clipboard, could i add something to the following piece of code which i am using :

`StringSelection ss = new StringSelection(textArea.getText());`
`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);`
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Contents copied to Clipboard");`

Comment: you can insert all the textarea string in list , and then check it against them , if not found add to clipboard , but it will decrease some performance here

Comment: Depends on why you have a graphical representation of the text, maybe the user has an in interest in seeing the duplicates (or wants to hardcopy it himself instead of clicking the button), in which case it is better to filter the clipboard.